# Add image to JPanel from other class

Tags: java, swing

I'm creating a roundabout simulation and until now I'm just adding images to the `JPanel` in `doDrawing(Graphics g)`. But my program communicates with a server which sends packets to spawn vehicles and pedestrians, so I also want to add images from another class now instead of adding them all in `doDrawing(Graphics g)`

Code of the main class (Roundabout(JFrame)) with inside the Surface class (JPanel).

```
public class Roundabout extends JFrame{

Track track=new Track();
TrafficLight trafficLight1=new TrafficLight(1);
TrafficLight trafficLight3=new TrafficLight(3);
TrafficLight trafficLight2=new TrafficLight(2);
TrafficLight trafficLight4=new TrafficLight(4);
TrafficLight trafficLight5=new TrafficLight(5);
Car car=new Car(412, 750); // south to west
Car car2=new Car(50,400); // west to south
Car car3=new Car(700,290); //east to south
Car car4=new Car(470,750);
Bus bus=new Bus();
Bicycle bicycle=new Bicycle();
Pedestrian pedestrian = new Pedestrian(571,750);
ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();

public static Map<Integer,TrafficLight> trafficLights = new HashMap<>();

byte[] array=new byte[]{0,2,1,1}; //test byte array

private Long startTime;
private long playTime = 4000;
private double i;

static TCPClient client;

Surface surface=new Surface();


class Surface extends JPanel {

private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {

    Dimension size = getSize();
    Insets insets = getInsets();

    int w = size.width - insets.left - insets.right;
    int h = size.height - insets.top - insets.bottom;

    /* Draw the track first */
    track.paint(g);

    /* Draw a car */
    //car.START_POS = new Point(412, 750);
    car.setCarLane(Lane.topLane);
    car.paint(g);
    cars.add(car); //add to list

    //car2.START_POS=new Point(50,400);
    car2.carRotation=180;
    car2.setCarLane(Lane.wsLane);
    car2.paint(g);
    cars.add(car2);

    car3.carRotation=360;
    car3.setCarLane(Lane.esLane);
    car3.paint(g);
    cars.add(car3);

    car4.setCarLane(Lane.seLane);
    car4.paint(g);
    cars.add(car4);

    /*Draw a bus*/
    bus.paint(g);

    /*Draw a bicycle */
    bicycle.setBicyclePath(Lane.bicyclePath);
    bicycle.paint(g);

    /*Draw a pedestrian */
    pedestrian.setPedestrianPath(Lane.pedesSePath);
    pedestrian.paint(g);

    /* Draw traffic light*/ 

    trafficLight1.setPosition(520, 333);
    trafficLight1.paint(g);

    trafficLight3.setPosition(100, 275);
    trafficLight3.paint(g);

    trafficLight2.setPosition(100, 400);
    trafficLight2.paint(g);

    trafficLight4.setPosition(355, 535);
    trafficLight4.paint(g);

    trafficLight5.setPosition(404, 535);
    trafficLight5.paint(g);


}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
    doDrawing(g);
}
}

public Roundabout(){
    initUI();

    trafficLights.put(trafficLight1.id, trafficLight1);
    trafficLights.put(trafficLight2.id,trafficLight2);
    trafficLights.put(trafficLight3.id,trafficLight3);
    trafficLights.put(trafficLight4.id,trafficLight4);
    trafficLights.put(trafficLight5.id,trafficLight5);
}

private void initUI() {

    setTitle("Roundabout");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    add(surface);

    //add start
    this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {// empty implementation of all
        // MouseListener`s methods
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getX() + "," + e.getY());
        }
    });
    //end add

    //setSize(580, 550);
    setSize(1618,850);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

}


public static void main(String[] args) {


    //Swing thread
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Roundabout roundabout=new Roundabout();
            roundabout.setVisible(true);    
            roundabout.moveCar();       
        }
    });             

}
```

Below my `Spawn` class where I'm trying to add a Pedestrian to the `Surface` `JPanel` but nothing is drawn on the Surface panel, I'm sure `spawnPedestrian()` is called. How can I make `spawnPedestrian()` work, that is draws on the `surface` panel?

Spawn.java

```
    public class Spawn {

    Roundabout roundabout = new Roundabout();

    public void spawnPedestrian(){
        Pedestrian p = new Pedestrian(50,50);

        System.out.println("Spawn me ");


        roundabout.surface.add(p);
        roundabout.surface.revalidate();
        roundabout.surface.repaint();
        roundabout.revalidate();
        roundabout.repaint();

    }
}
```

Comment: You'd benefit from applying MVC to this problem. Search the internet for "Model View Controller" for more information

Comment: Your Spawn creates a new Roundabout. Don't you want to use the one you've created in main?

Comment: @ControlAltDel I know MVC but don't use it in this project. Maybe I would benefit from applying it here but I keep this structure for now.

Comment: @JPMoresmau How can I access the JFrame (Roundabout) and JPanel (Surface) and draw on the Surface panel?

Comment: Pass the roundabout as a parameter to spawnPedestrian?

Comment: @JPMoresmau tried that, but no luck it does't work, and with doesn't work I mean the same result as before.

Comment: Are you sure your doDrawing method does not draw over any extra component you add? You add the pedestrian to your surface, but then you draw everything on top...

Comment: @JPMoresmau maybe that's the case, any idea how prevent from that?

Comment: why is the question voted to close ??? explain please